# find nCr combinations for array items

Tags: javascript, math

I have a problem with my recursive function to find **nCr** objects in Array.

this works only when `r=2`, means only when going 1 level inside.

it seems my temporary `'a'` array gets all messed up when `r > 2`

```
// find nCr combinations in Array
// n -> keys.length
// r -> number of combination to extract (cross = r-1 )

console.clear();
var keys = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

// cross = 'r'-1, s = start point, a = array
function recursive(cross, s, a){
    for( var i=s; i < keys.length; i++ ){
        if( !cross ){
            var b = a.slice(0);
            b.push( keys[i] );
            set.push( b );
        }
        else{ 
            a.splice(-1, 1);
            a.push(keys[i]); 
            recursive(cross-1, i+1, a); 
        }
    }
}

var set = [];
recursive(1, 0, []);
console.log( set );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do in your `else` condition: note that `a.splice(-1,1)` removes the last element of `a`, but you start with `a` empty, when there is nothing to be removed. Even if the code works for `r=2`, this is a sign that you're doing something wrong. (In fact, each time you go one level deeper, `a` starts with just the same number of elements as it had at the previous level, so you're removing some element you shouldn't be touching.)

Here's a very slight modification of your algorithm that works correctly. I just changed the order of statements inside the `else` condition.

```
var keys = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

function recursive(cross, s, a) {
    for( var i=s; i < keys.length; i++ ){
        if( !cross ){
            var b = a.slice(0);
            b.push( keys[i] );
            set.push( b );
        }
        else{ 
            a.push(keys[i]); 
            recursive(cross-1, i+1, a); 
            a.splice(-1, 1);
        }
    }
}

var set = [];
recursive(4, 0, []);
console.log( set );
```

This last part should print all (6 choose 5)=6 combinations of 5 elements out of `keys`.

The idea is that now in each call of the function, `splice` only removes the element that was added in that call, rather than something added in some other function call possibly at some other level. This also guarantees that `a` remains the same at the end as at the beginning. (Everything you add you remove again.)

This is a common pattern you'll see when writing recursive functions: do some modification, call the function recursively, then do some cleanup that reverses the modification.

BTW, slightly cleaner code (without the `cross = r-1` obfuscation) is in [the first revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6361505/1).

Comment: @vsync: Don't be. Recursion (and binary search) is notoriously hard to get right; even experienced programmers can get it right only if are most careful.

Comment: thank you for your time kind sir. much appreciated and sure would help others that might come across in a need for something of this sort. thumbs up!