# Combination of a letter using recursive

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, combinations

Suppose, if I give **'ABC' as input** then then I want **'ABC', 'ACB', 'CAB', 'CBA', 'BAC', 'BCA'**. Each word has **combination of n!** where n is length of letter. I think recursion can make it easier. Here is my code written in javascript :

```
function reArrange(word)
{
    console.log(word);
    if (word.length < 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    else if (word.length == 0) {
        return ('');
    }
    else {
        for (var _i = 0; _i < word.length; _i++) {
            var temp = word[_i];
            for (var _j = 0; _j < word.length; _j++) {
                if (_i != _j) {
                    return word[_i] + reArrange(word.slice(_i, word.length));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please use detailed comment.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359344/find-ncr-combinations-for-array-items

Comment: I'm really curious as to what is the use case for this

Comment: What is the question? If you want code review, post it in [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "I think recursion can make it easier" (that's the closest thing I can find to a question or request in your question) - the function *is* recursive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function combinations(current_string, actual_string, seen) {
    var result = [];
    if (current_string.length === actual_string.length) {
        return [current_string];
    }
    actual_string.forEach(function(currentChar, index) {
        if (seen.indexOf(index) === -1) {
            result = [].concat.apply(result, combinations(current_string
                + currentChar, actual_string, seen.concat(index)));
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(combinations("", "ABC".split(""), []));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA' ]
```

**Note:** This program works under the assumption that the characters in input string will be unique.

There are three parameters passed to this function. First one is the current string which was built with recursion, second is the array of characters from the actual string, third one is the list of indices already seen in the recursion tree.

The first if condition is the base condition of this recursive solution. If the length of the current string generated is equal to the actual string's length, we have no characters left to process and this is one of the combinations. So, we return that.

If that condition is not met, for each character in actual string, we check if it has been used already (we compare the indices with the indices in the `seen`). If it is already used in the current recursion, ignore that. Otherwise, concate that with the current string and include this in the seen variable and recurse now.

The result of the recursion will be an array of strings. We need to flatten them (concatenate all the elements of the inner arrays). So, we use `[].concat.apply`.

Finally, we return the gathered result and here is how the recursion tree looks like

[image: Combinations Recursion Tree]

Comment: I personally dislike "code only" answers, especially when it seems the OP is trying to understand something - and not only get it to work. You should put some effort in explaining what logic the code is implementing.

Comment: @amit Please check now, I have included a little explanation with a diagram.

Comment: I cannot judge on the js code, as I am not familiar with it, but the explanations are pretty good now. nice answer.